# Missing Keyword Error in Oracle - Wrong Syntax WHERE Expression

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle SQL, I'm being asked to do some scenarios to learn the different expressions and so on.

I'm currently working on this statement but I keep having trouble with syntax and trying to get my expressions in the correct place.

If you don't mind taking a look at what I'm doing wrong and helping me learn the correct syntax I'd appreciate it a lot.

I have to find everything in the Sale, SaleDetail, OrderStatus, Warehouse, User and StockDetail tables.

The fields I need to find are saleno, serialstart, serialend, the product description (label field), sale status (saleid (I think)), WarehouseName (WH.NAME)

Here below is the code I've written so far.

```
SELECT
S.SALENO,
SD.SERIALSTART,
SD.SERIALEND,
SDT.LABEL,
USR.USERNAME,
WH.NAME
FROM
ITR_SALE,
ITR_SALEDETAIL,
ITR_ORDER,
ITR_WAREHOUSE,
ITR_USER,
ITR_STOCKDETAIL
JOIN ITR_SALE S
JOIN ITR_SALEDETAIL SD ON S.ID = SD.SALENO
JOIN ITR_WAREHOUSE WH ON SD.ID = WH.NAME
JOIN ITR_ORDER ODR ON WH.ID = ODR.STATUSID
JOIN ITR_USER USR ON ODR.ID = USR.USERNAME
JOIN ITR_STOCKDETAIL ON USR.ID = SDT.LABEL
WHERE S.LASTSTATUSCHANGETIME 
BETWEEN ('2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59')
AND STATUSID = ('COMPLETED');
```

Below follows the error message

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 21 Column: 1
```

EDIT:

Finished code below, changed a few expressions and conditions.

```
SELECT
S.SALENO,
SD.SERIALSTART,
SD.SERIALEND,
SDA.LABEL,
USR.USERNAME,
WH.NAME
FROM 
ITR_SALE S
INNER JOIN
ITR_SALEDETAIL SD ON S.ID = SD.SALEID
INNER JOIN
ITR_ORDERSTATUS ODS ON SD.ID = ODS.ID
INNER JOIN
ITR_WAREHOUSE WH ON ODS.ID = WH.NAME
INNER JOIN
ITR_USER USR ON WH.ID = USR.USERNAME
INNER JOIN
ITR_STOCKDETAIL SDA ON USR.ID = SDA.LABEL
WHERE 'DATE' BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
AND S.STATUSID = '4';`
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the last two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper join syntax. Edit. Need to remove parenthesis from last line or user IN clause.

```
SELECT
S.SALENO,
SD.SERIALSTART,
SD.SERIALEND,
SDT.LABEL,
USR.USERNAME,
WH.NAME
FROM
ITR_SALE S INNER JOIN ITR_SALEDETAIL SD ON S.ID = SD.SALENO
INNER JOIN ITR_SALEDETAIL SD ON S.ID = SD.SALENO
INNER JOIN ITR_WAREHOUSE WH ON SD.ID = WH.NAME
INNER JOIN ITR_ORDER ODR ON WH.ID = ODR.STATUSID
INNER JOIN ITR_USER USR ON ODR.ID = USR.USERNAME
INNER JOIN ITR_STOCKDETAIL STD ON USR.ID = SDT.LABEL
WHERE S.LASTSTATUSCHANGETIME 
BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59'
AND STATUSID = 'COMPLETED';
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the BETWEEN condition also.

Comment: Right. Missed that. Thanks

Comment: Sorted, thanks for the help, I ended up changing some of the statement but it ultimately ran after a few errors.